# Easier way of seperating dictionary items by value types

Tags: c#

I have a script that contains these functions:

```
 public Dictionary<string, float> GetFloatVariables(){
    Dictionary<string, float> floatDict = new Dictionary<string, float>();
    foreach (var variable in variables)
    {
        var type = variableTypes[variable.Key];

        if (type == typeof(float))
        {
            float value = System.Convert.ToSingle(variable.Value);
            floatDict.Add(variable.Key, value);
        }
    }
    return floatDict;
}

public Dictionary<string, bool> GetBoolVariables(){
    Dictionary<string, bool> boolDict = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
    foreach (var variable in variables)
    {
        var type = variableTypes[variable.Key];

        if (type == typeof(bool))
        {
            bool value = System.Convert.ToBoolean(variable.Value);
            boolDict.Add(variable.Key, value);
        }
    }
    return boolDict;
}

public Dictionary<string, string> GetStringVariables(){
    Dictionary<string, string> stringDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    foreach (var variable in variables)
    {
        var type = variableTypes[variable.Key];

        if (type == typeof(string))
        {
            string value = System.Convert.ToString(variable.Value);
            stringDict.Add(variable.Key, value);
        }
    }
    return stringDict;
}
```

While this way of doing things is working, I feel like its kind of redundant to loop through  "variables" dictionary every time I want to call all 3 methods.

May I know if there is a better way of doing this? Perhaps using LINQ

Comment: Then return some class or tuple containing all 3 dictionaries? Though, perhaps you are solving the wrong problem. What type is `variable`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use *generics* `<T>` to have one method instead of three and *Linq* to get rid of loops:

```
using System.Linq;

...

public Dictionary<string, T> GetVariables<T>() => variables
  .Where(pair => pair.Value is T)
  .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => (T) (pair.Value));
```

Usage:

```
var boolDictionary = GetVariables<bool>();

var floatDictionary = GetVariables<float>();

var stringDictionary = GetVariables<string>();
```

Comment: A potentially difference to the question is, that you use *cast*, while the original code uses *convert*. Could lead to different results, depending on the source data (which is not specified). Maybe a useage of `TypeDescriptor.GetConverter()` could help to better mimic the original code.

Comment: The type check is done twice. First in the `.Where()` clause and then in the conditional expression. I think the second check can be omitted and done via a hard cast.